# nhibernate mapping decimal with precision and scale

Tags: c#, nhibernate

inside db I have field which is `decimal(9, 6)`

Nhibernate save this data with losing last digit in format `decimal(9, 5)`

Question is how to map field  using nhib. mapping by code to use precision 9,6

```
Property(
   x=>x.Longitude
   // precision and scale                  
);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `Longitude`?

Comment: Could you check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5244781/326543) works for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set explicitly to this type precision and scale like this

```
Property(
    x => x.Longitude,
    m =>
        {
            m.Precision(9);
            m.Scale(6);
        }
 );
```

or you can set in conventions to match all decimals in your app, this is outside of this question (just an idea).

Hope this helps