# OCI-22053: overflow error

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to retrieve a `List` from an Oracle database using N-Hibernate. In the database, some field has a value with higher precision (20-22  digit) and the C# class has a property with `double` as its type.

How is it possible to store data from the database into a C# `List` in this situation?

**`TestTable`**

```
Oracle Field - TestField
       Value -  -3845585825867490000000000000000
```

**Oracle Column DataType**

```
   FLOAT - TestField
```

**C# Property**

```
[Property(Column = "TestField", NotNull = true)]
public virtual double TestField { get; set; }
```

**C# Code**

```
ICriteria crit = this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TestTable));
IList<TestTable> list = crit.List<TestTable>(); //got error at this line
```

I can't use `ROUND` as i am using N Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the datatype of the C# property to a `decimal` - I think it has enough precision to handle your situation.

It looks like there's some further talk on `decimal` mappings for NHibernate fields [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427728/nhibernate-mapping-decimal-with-precision-and-scale).

Answer (score 0):

[`FLOAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Data-Types.htm#d23532e556) within Oracle is a `NUMBER` subtype and have to be mapped to a .Net `decimal`. It does not match a .Net `double`.

If what you actually need is something like a .Net `double`, use `BINARY_DOUBLE` (or `BINARY_FLOAT`) in Oracle.