# NHibernate decimal precision on SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate

Im trying to call a stored procedure sending a decimal called `rate` as one of its parameters, but its losing the decimal precision when executing the query.

This is the code on server side:

```
IQuery query = Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec SaveExchangeRate @Rate = :rate, @OtherParameter = :otherParameter");
query.SetDecimal("rate", exchangeRate.Rate);
query.SetInt32("otherParamter", otherParamter);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

At this point, `exchangeRate.Rate` is `0.0000631046`.

When I open a SQL profiler, is giving me:

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec SaveExchangeRate @Rate = @p0, @OtherParamter = @p1',N'@p0 decimal(28,5),@p1 int',@p0=6,@p1=4
```

As you see, the precision is `decimal(28,5)`, but inside the stored procedure, the precision needed is `decimal(19,10)`, and the number sent to the SQL database is just `6`, losing its precision. After that, the number persisted is `0.0000600000`, losing a lot of decimals.

How can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5243486/497356

Comment: yes, but, as you see, the value doesnt came from a property, so its not mapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this isn't straightforward at all and there might be a better way, but you could use `TypeFactory` to retrieve a `decimal` type with the scale and precision you want, then use `SetParameter` instead of `SetDecimal`:

```
IType decimalType = TypeFactory.Basic("Decimal(19,10)");

IQuery query = Session.CreateSQLQuery("....");
query.SetParameter("rate", exchangeRate.Rate, decimalType);
query.SetInt32("otherParamter", otherParamter);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

This seems to send the correct number to the database.